# Windows Powershell - Returning and supplying variables to functions does not work

Tags: function, powershell, scope, powershell-2.0, subroutine

I have a problem Im hoping someone is able to help with...

I have the following code that has a user menu and recursively searches for text files and files containing the string "hello", it then prints a html file with the results:

```
Foreach ($Target in $Targets){     #ip address from the text file supplied

Function gettextfiles { 

    Write-Output "Collating Detail for $Target"

    $Results = Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Recurse -Include *.txt
    Write-Output "output from recursively searching for text files $Results"
    $MyReport = Get-CustomHTML "$Target Audit"
    $MyReport += Get-CustomHeader0  "$Target Details"
    $MyReport += Get-CustomHeader "2" "Text files found"

    foreach ($file in $Results) {
        $MyReport += Get-HTMLDetail "Path to the file" ($file)
    }

    $MyReport += Get-CustomHeaderClose

    return $MyReport
}

Function gethello {
    $Results = Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Recurse | Select-String -pattern hello | group path | select -ExpandProperty name
    Write-Output "output from recursively looking for the string hello $Results"

    $MyReport += Get-CustomHeader "2" "Hello Strings Found"

    foreach ($file in $Results) {
        $MyReport += Get-HTMLDetail "Path to the file" ($file)
    }

    $MyReport += Get-CustomHeaderClose

    return $MyReport
}

####################################################################
# To create the html document from the data gathered in the above functions

Function printeverything([string]$MyReport) {

    $Date = Get-Date
    $Filename = "C:\Desktop" + "_" + $date.Hour + $date.Minute + "_" + $Date.Day + "-" + $Date.Month + "-" + $Date.Year + $Date.Second + ".htm"
    $MyReport | out-file -encoding ASCII -filepath $Filename
    Write "HTML file saved as $Filename"

}
###################################################################
User input menu, call the functions the user chooses then when they press 3 creates the html file

do {
[int]$xMenuChoiceA = 0
while ( $xMenuChoiceA -lt 1 -or $xMenuChoiceA -gt 4 ){
Write-host "1. Get Text Files"
Write-host "2. Get Files With The String Hello"
[Int]$xMenuChoiceA = read-host "Please enter an option 1 to 4..." }
Switch( $xMenuChoiceA ){
  1{gettextfiles}
  2{gethello}
  3{printeverything "$MyReport"}
default{<#run a default action or call a function here #>}
}
} while ($xMenuChoiceA -ne 4) 

}  #ending bracket of Targets foreach
```

**The problem I am having:**

Using the user menu I can successfully run the script to find text files and to find files containing the string hello, any results it finds are added to `$MyReport` using functions that construct html for the html file. **<-- This all workds perfectly**

**However when I try to then call the `printeverything` function with the `$MyReport` variable so that it will create the HTML file for me, it does not work.**

The code to create the HTML file works perefectly as I have tested it, **I believe the problem is that the `$MyReport` variable is not being passed to the `printeverything` function correctly but I cannot workout what I am doing wrong**

As I am new to Powershell your help with this would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `do-while` look, `$MyReport` is just passed to the `print everything` method. But, it will not be in scope at that point as you are just assigning to `$MyReport` within the functions.

Try using `$MyReport` as `$script:MyReport` everywhere, so that it will be in script scope. This is not the ideal solution, but should be good enough to get you started.

Also, you might want to read up on pipeline / function output in powershell. You are using it wrong - http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/06/15/things-that-trip-newbies-in-powershell-pipeline-output/

Comment: I shall give that a try and certainly look at the link you provided as well...you said this solution was not ideal, what would be the ideal way to do this then? thanks for your help

Comment: @perl-user - Ideal way would be to have proper scope and return value from function and assign the returned value to a variable in your local scope and work with that by passing it to other functions etc.

Comment: Yes I agree, and thats what I am trying to achieve. I have tried to do it that way a number of times, still with no luck. I dont know if its something syntactically I am doing wrong but I cant get it to work (I can do that kind of thing easily in perl but having trouble in powershell). Would you be able to show me an example of how this would be done correctly, thanks for your help